# HTML5 source element's media attribute question

Tags: html

What does it mean for instance that a value like all is suitable for all devices? What are the devices? Can you list some devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would mean phone, tablet, computer, projector, etc. All means that when the web browser parsing your page gets to the media attribute, it will say to itself "I am a phone, this element says it works on all - that includes me"